# Creating a subcorpus in R-Studio

Tags: r, rstudio, text-mining

Currently i am conducting a text-mining-analysis with R-Studio. I established a pool of txt-files as my directory.

Now i am wondering: Is it possible to create a subcorpus from that files just by using R-Studio? Currently i want to create a subcorpus containing only and all documents that contain a certain Word/Lemma (e.g. "Afrik"). Thank You!

Comment: Do you mean using only IDE operations? RStudio is an IDE that enables rich interaction with R. Do you mean programming or just clicking in an IDE? If you mean "R" then you need to add the R tag to your question. RStudio is not R. And, if you do mean just IDE operations, that's a fool's errand IMO.

Comment: Thank you, Sir! I am using RStudio indeed. I loaded the text mining packages into R Studio. To be honest, i dont even know, what an IDE operation is. All i want is to analyse only some articles from my working directory - only those which contain a special word. So i am wondering, if i have to create a new subfolder in my explorer or if there is a smart way to use the program itself to select the relevant txt-files.

Comment: roger that. are you looking to subset the corpus by file name or by the contents of the file? If the former, you can use `dir()` or `list.files()` (they are the same function, really) and specify a pattern. If it's the contents, you either need to use operating system commands like `grep` to identify the files that have the target words in the contents or use R and `readLines()` + `grepl()` to do the identification after iterating through file lists (which you can also build with `dir()` or `list.files()`).

Comment: Thank you Sir! I am looking to subset by contents of the file. The file names aren't specific enough. Your suggestions look like a viable way. I will try it as soon, as my corpus is complete. Maybe I will return then with a specified question regarding the commands.

Now I will try to close the topic and to award you for your kind reply.